# CakePHP find conditions not working

Tags: cakephp

I have an action for CommentsView in which i want to retrieve all the comments with a condition that Comment.post_id = Post.id but when i debug it, it gives me an empty array.

Action CommentsView:

```
public function commentsview()
{ 

    $commentsview = $this->Comment->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Comment.post_id' => 'Post.id')));

    if (!empty($this->params['requested'])) 
    {            
        return $commentsview;        
    } 

}
```

Comment: This is the query which is running at the back without adding any condition SELECT `Comment`.`id`, `Comment`.`comments`, `Comment`.`created`, `Comment`.`user_id`, `Comment`.`note_id`, `Note`.`id`, `Note`.`user_id`, `Note`.`notes`, `Note`.`created`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`gender`, `User`.`dob`, `User`.`image`, `User`.`tmp_name`, `User`.`search` FROM `fyp`.`comments` AS `Comment` LEFT JOIN `fyp`.`notes` AS `Note` ON (`Comment`.`note_id` = `Note`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `fyp`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Comment`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) NOTE:

Answer (score 2):

You are providing the condition for a join which is passed differently.
The **conditions** arguments are for a **WHERE** clause.

But you only need to specify:

```
$comments = $this->Comment->find('all',
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Comment.post_id' => $post_id
        )
    )
);
```

Or when you are fetching the comments from the PostsController

```
$comments = $this->Post->Comment->find('all',
    array(
        'fields'=>array(
            'Comment.*'
        )
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Post.id' => $post_id
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What is $post_id in you first example?

Comment: Hope you got my point? I want that post_id field of comment table must be equals to id field of POST table 

Comment.post_id = Post.id

and i am doing all this in CommentsController

Comment: Your 'conditions' only make sense if it's supposed to be a join condition. But cakephp joins the comments automatically. So if you want all comments for all posts: $this->loadModel('Post'); $this->Post->find('all');

Comment: i want to display Comments related to that specific Post ... This is why i am doing it? I am confused if i am doing right or wrong :S

Comment: Also when i do not add any condition and view a post of id 41 like posts/view/41 , it also shows me the comments related to Post of id 37

Comment: If you **only** want to display the comments without the post itself then use the first query I provided. Of course you need to know the **id of the post** to which the comments belong. Other that read: [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), you are a little bit confused

Comment: Yes i read that but i guess you are not getting me or i am not that clear...


I have a post and its id is 37 ... now i want only those comments to be display who have 37 in their Post_id field ...

Answer (score 0):

change your function to this:

```
public function commentsview($post_id=null) { 

    $commentsview = $this->Comment->find('all', array('conditions'=>
                                            array('Comment.post_id' => $post_id))
                                        );
    debug($commentsview);
    exit;

}
```

Visit this URL: `yourapp.com/comments/commentsview/37`

The comments will be output. Now you know it's working. Then you can pass it to the view or do whatever.

You have asked similar questions several times. This is a BASIC concept.